# Not able to install ProtonVPN

Tags: install

I am trying to install protonVPN but I am getting this error. The file is located in my downloads folder and the filename is correct. I am following the instructions on the protonmail website.
Below are my results.
What am I missing?

Thanks.

```
ava@Earth:~/Downloads$ ls
protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb
ava@Earth:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb
[sudo] password for ava:             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb'
```

Comment: try to install it with gdebi. It will install all dependences and show the exect error

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install it manually? If not try downloading the Debian package ProtonVPN and then use dpkg:

`sudo dpkg -i protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.0-1_all.deb`

If dpkg is complaining about missing dependencies, then use apt-get -f install after running dpkg, that is the best advice I can give you, it did not work for me though, but maybe it will help you?